# how do i set every core to a different frequency

Tags: cpufreq

I tried to use `sudo cpufreq-set -c -f` to change a single core's frequency, while all the other cores' frequency changes simultaneously, is this because my CPU cannot support achieving this?  My CPU is Intel® Core™ `i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz` with 8 cores(or 16 CPUs)

Comment: Basically, you don't.  Each CPU *core* doesn't have its frequency/speed governor, each master CPU processor itself has typically only one control/governor for its speed/frequency.  You can't control it per core, only per CPU unit (which is all the cores simultaneously)

Answer (score 2):

The is only one master CPU clock Phase Locked Loop (PLL) on that Intel processor, so there is only  one active CPU frequency that is for all CPUs. Votes into the PLL are from each CPU as a function of what their CPU scaling driver wants and if they are in a deep idle state (relinquishing their vote) or not. If HWP (HardWare Pstate) control is enabled then the processor decides the vote, with only guidelines from the CPU scaling driver. The highest CPU frequency active vote wins.